# css code is not applying between 730px to 760px

Tags: html, css

I am making footer responsive.I have write css code for footer column. Which are as below

**CSS**

```
@media (min-width:300px) and (max-width:749px) {
 ------ css code---
}
@media (min-width:750px) and (max-width:1200px) {
  ----css code---
}
```

Now I didnot get result for width in between 730px to 760px.
Footer is distorted between this range.Which should be fine up to 749px as it above code.

Comment: Can you put your CSS and minimal HTML in a http://jsfiddle.net?

Comment: Because unfortunately as it is there's not enough information to answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this it works fine for me.

```html
@media screen and (max-width: 1200px) {
  .your-css-class{
    /*your css styles here*/
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 750) {
  .your-css-class {
    /*your css styles here*/
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 730) {
  .your-css-class {
    /*your css styles here*/
  }
}
```